# Why does using the subfigure command break my Beamer presentation, and what should I replace it with?

Tags: beamer, subfloats

I'm trying to update a Beamer presentation created waaaaay back in 2008 by LyX. It uses the `subfig` package to create a series of slides that appear to update a single image on the same page.

Unfortunately, it no longer seems to render with `pdflatex`. I exported the LyX document to LaTeX to isolate the problem, and the minimal document that demonstrates it is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[H]

\subfloat[Before]{
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.45\textwidth]{IX_ICA2}
}

\subfigure[After]{
  \includegraphics<1>[width=0.45\textwidth]{IX_ICA2.pdf}
  \includegraphics<2>[width=0.45\textwidth]{IX_k-2.pdf}
}

\protect\caption{Overall caption for the whole figurey thing}

\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I run it through `pdflatex` (v3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13), it stops with this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@doifinframe ...IX_ICA2} } \par \subfigure 
                                                  [After]{ \includegraphics ...
l.22 \end{frame}
```

If I remove the entire `\subfigure{...}` command, it renders fine.

According to the manual, the `subfigure` command is only included in the `subfig` package for backwards compatibility. But I can't figure out what combination of commands to replace it with.

What's the best way to achieve the original effect here?

Answer (score 1):

The error message about `\subfigure` being an undefined control sequence goes away if you replace `\subfigure` with `\subfloat`. Can you make do with `\subfloat`?

Comment: Yes, `subfloat` appears to achieve the same effect.